# appache2 server on Azure VM get Error : "This site can’t be reached *.*.*.*"

Tags: apache, azure, networking, server, azure-devops

i get this error for installation script that worked perfect on EC2 vm but now seems that i can't reach the site , should i add some inbound rule or something to enable apache2 server ? the error in the chrome is

```
This site can’t be reached *.*.*.*.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Network Security Group

Azure VMs do not have any ports open firewall ports by default unless you open them when you provision your VM. When you created your Azure VM in the Azure Portal, you likely created a Network Security Group for the VM. If you didn't specify any ports to open during the VM's creation, you'll need to open up the VM's firewall.

### To Open Ports

To open up the ports on the firewall, head out to the Azure Portal (where you set up the VM). Find the VM in the list of resources. It should take you to a page for your VM where the name, status, location, size, IP address, etc will be displayed. On the left side, you'll have a vertical menu > Select `Networking`. From there, you'll be able to see currently active firewall rules for the VM. Since you're likely missing `HTTP` (80) and `HTTPS`, select `add inbound port rule`. From the dropdown for service, select `HTTP` and assign a name/priority. Perform the same options, except this time selecting `HTTPS` (443). Press save and test. You should be able to access Apache running on the VM.

### Additional Troubleshooting

The script you used may have inadvertently set up the VM's `iptables`. You can view Linux's firewall with `sudo iptables -L` to verify that no firewall rules have been enabled. Since Azure handles the firewall, you shouldn't *need* any iptables rules, but they could always be added for additional security.

This answer assumes that you do not have Azure's Load Balancing servers installed in front of the VM.

Comment: thanks a lot , i tried just open port 80 and 443 but when i opened spesific http and https it worked